# I could not find a LaTeX character sheet code for 5e D&D that would work without errors

Tags: character-sheets, tool-recommendation

I'm looking for LaTeX code for a 5e D&D character sheet because there is not enough room for equipment in the original.

I found some, but they did not execute well so I'm looking for one that looks just like the D&D Beyond sheet. My idea is a working LaTeX code with a clear equipment section that I can easily copy&paste for another page just for equipment. Please let me know if something like that exists.

If not, I'd like a LaTeX code for the D&D Beyond sheet and would try to change it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic as stated, you might want adjust your question into asking about how to do it and you might get a good answer that way.

Comment: How is this off topic? I need a resource to play D&D which is a RPG. 
This is much more the forum to ask about RPG resources than the Latex stack exchange, where users wouldn't know what I mean by character sheet

Comment: To learn more about shopping questions, you might want to start with this: [What actually is a shopping question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/what-actually-is-a-shopping-question).

Comment: I don't think asking for a technical resource constitutes a shopping question, especially when the question is about whether one exists at all.

Comment: An alternative avenue is to take the sheets you found which had errors then ask LaTeX.SE why it doesn't compile properly.